# Weird date filter behavior between US and UK Settings : VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am applying filter to a column of Dates and its working fine on my machine (US Regional Settings). When I send the workbook to users in UK, the same filter fails (UK Regional Settings). There is no error, the filter simply fails and not rows are filtered. IF I manually set the Date returned in VBA code, the filter works.

```
'/ ALERT_DATE : named Range containing date. Cell Format is set as date.
'/ Column 5 in wksTemp contains all valid dates in correct format.

'/ Following code works fine in US Regional Settings.
    wksTemp.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    wksTemp.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    "<" & wksSettings.Range("ALERT_DATE")

    wksTemp.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wksDest.Cells(1, 1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'/ Same code fails with UK settings.
```

Tried, `Value2`, `Format`, `DateSerial` nothings seems to Filter the rows in UK format.

In UK settings, If I manually set the value of `"<" & wksSettings.Range("ALERT_DATE")` for example `28/05/2017` in the Filter, it works.

Any ideas. How to rectify this so that it works for UK and US both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the Date issue with DateFilter :)

Simplest fix, convert your date to long. Works since beginning of VBA or at least I think so.

```
wksSettings.Range("ALERT_DATE") ---->> Clng(wksSettings.Range("ALERT_DATE"))
```

Try this:

```
  wksTemp.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    wksTemp.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    "<" & Clng(wksSettings.Range("ALERT_DATE"))

    wksTemp.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wksDest.Cells(1, 1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

No tested, but should work.

Comment: pheww... can't believe how many things I tried and how much time spent. Switching . between regions is a pain in the back itself. !!!!THANKS!!!!!